# In my service integration, I found a NullPointerException when instantiating class of another service

Tags: nullpointerexception

I cannot seem to figure out in my service integration why my instantiation of the class of another service returns null even when I can see the class in the jar in the library.

Please see my code here:

public class OAuthFacadeClientImpl implements OAuthFacadeClient {

```
/**
 * oauth facade
 */
private OAuthFacade supergwOauthFacade;

/** LOGGER */
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OAuthFacadeClientImpl.class);

@Override
public AccessTokenRevokeResult revokeToken(String merchantId, String userId,
                                                           String scope) {

    AccessTokenRevokeRequest revokeRequest = new AccessTokenRevokeRequest();
    revokeRequest.setAccessToken(userId);
    revokeRequest.setClientId(merchantId);
    revokeRequest.setExtRequestId(scope);

    LogUtil.info(LOGGER, "revokeRequest value = " + revokeRequest);

    AccessTokenRevokeResult revokeResult = supergwOauthFacade
            .revokeToken(revokeRequest.getClientId(), revokeRequest.getAccessToken(),
                    revokeRequest.getExtRequestId());

    SALResultChecker.checkAndAssert(revokeResult);

    return revokeResult;

}

/**
 * Setter method for property <tt>oAuthFacade</tt>.
 *
 * @param oAuthFacade value to be assigned to property miniAppQueryFacade
 */
public void setOAuthFacade(OAuthFacade oAuthFacade) {
    this.supergwOauthFacade = oAuthFacade;
}
```

}

[Breakpoints of my code upon debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GMXY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to instantiate an object of type `OAuthFacade` prior to using this method `revokeToken(...)` and feed that reference using your setter method (e.i., `setOAuthFacade(...)`) so that `supergwOauthFacade` will not point to nothing and avoid getting `NullPointerException`. Good LUCK